# How make this expression for html helpers?

Tags: c#, linq, html-helper

i have two classes

```
public class LocalizedString {
    public string Ru { get; set; }
    public string Kk { get; set; }
    public string En { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
    public LocalizedString FirstName { get; set; }
    public LocalizedString LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I need make expression like `x => x.FirstName.Ru`
for `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName.Ru)`

and for `LastName` and it must depend from current culture

How do it?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how make method wich return me nedeed expression?

Comment: Setting `@model Person` on razor view
use `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName.Ru)` can make it...

Comment: i wiil have many properties with type localized string, and i need method wich will accept name of property and model type and return me expression with this property and lang, ru kk

Comment: So, Did  you want to set culture by  `LocalizedString `?

Comment: No, LocalizedString just all values, translates. a wanna get cuurent lang from localized string just with method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, string>> GetMember<T>(
        Expression<Func<T, LocalizedString>> expression) {
        MemberExpression member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        PropertyInfo propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression propertyLambda = Expression.Property(param, propInfo.Name);

        propertyLambda = Expression.Property(propertyLambda, "Ru");

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(propertyLambda, param);
    }
```